# WinForms Inheritance

Tags: winforms, generics, inheritance, designer

I have been using form inheritance for a while now but without doing much research with the following approach. Simply create a new class instead of a form and inherit from an existing form and convert required controls to protected as needed. Visual Studio 2010 designer works like a charm. If more control is required, you can always override base methods.

I am now creating generic forms as follows:
`partial class EntityCollectionEditor < T > : Form where T : ISomeInterface < T >`

Forms such as this when inherited by simple non-designer classes give the following error:
**The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: XYZ. The base class EntityCollectionEditor could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.**

A quick solution would be nice but I'm also looking for a good resource/article to educate myself.

Comment: You cannot inherit from this class and use the designer on the inherited form class.  The designer needs to be able to create an instance of the base class, it can't supply the T type parameter.

Comment: Let me put it this way. The base form has no visual elements. It creates everything at runtime. I did, however, include one button on it. What I should have done is used a simple class instead, inherit from form and make it generic. VS seems to generate the backing resource files correctly from there on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the winforms designer does not support generic forms/controls.

The only work around I have used is to create a specific form type:

```
class GenericBaseForm<T> : Form
{ }

class IntForm : GenericBaseForm<Int>
{ }

class StringForm : GenericBaseForm<String>
{ }
```

The specific forms can now be used in the designer.  Unfortunatly, if you have a lot of specific forms, its probably not an ideal solution.

Comment: Not sure about that. Try creating a new class XYZ and code it to read `class XYZ<T>: Form {}`. Double clicking this class brings up a the base form in the designer. Not sure if this can be relied on for production though. Don't want complications down the line.